# Sending file with other attributes using vertx web client

Tags: forms, vert.x

I want to build an architecture in which one `vertx`-based backend microservice can send a file (which it receives from some UI) to another microservice.

I know that `vertx` web client would allow sending multipart data form, or streaming but not both. The UI (created with `reactjs`) can do it easily but the same does not apply to `vertx`.

Does anybody know how this could be achieved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

from the backend vertx application you should be able to create a vertx client which will post a file.

https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/core-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/core/http/upload/Client.java

Comment: I know it can send a file. But what I want to do here is to send a file along with a few key-value pairs. Just like when you submit a form that uploads a file and some text fields. Either that, or is there any way I can submit 1 data file, and 1 json file?